# How to make package dependencies/requirements dependent on conditional symbols?

Tags: delphi, build-automation, delphi-2009

I have a package `Package1` which depends on package `PackDependency`. The **.dpk** of `Package1` contains this:

```
requires
  vcl,
  rtl,
  PackDependency,
  dbrtl;
```

Now I want to have this dependeny only if a conditional symbol `CONDITION` is defined. Thus I change the **.dpk** file manually to:

```
requires
  vcl,
  rtl,
  {$IFDEF CONDITION}
  PackDependency,
  {$ENDIF}
  dbrtl;
```

But is this enough? I am worried about the **.dproj** files.

I have two packages like `Package1` I want to do the above with. One of them has the following line in its **.dproj** file:

```
  <DCCReference Include="PackDependency.dcp"/>
```

The other packages' **.dproj** does *not* contain this line even though the package is also dependent on `PackDependency`.

This raises some questions:

- Is it possible to `require` a package based on a conditional symbol?
- If yes, do I have to do something to the .dproj file? And if yes, can I get in trouble if certain areas of the file are modified by Delphi?
- Why is the `<DCCReference Include...>` line above included in one of the .dproj files but not in the other (even though both packages have the dependency in their .dpk and also shown in the Delphi Project Manager)?
- I suspect different behavior when building from Delphi and from command line using msbuild. The former might look into the .dpk file - but does the latter?

My ultimate goal is building from command line using msbuild. So different behavior between command line and IDE is also important information for me.

Comment: It seems like this is easily tested...

Comment: I want to avoid "Works now, breaks later". But I am testing right now. Would be nice though if there was a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will work fine as you have explained in the question, until you add a new unit to the package! At that point, your conditional defines will be automatically erased by the IDE, and you'll have to put them in again (which is annoying).

I know of no elegant way to avoid this!

Don't worry about the DPROJ files so much... as these are supposed to be maintained by the IDE, so removing a dependency in the DPK source should (upon compile) remove any corresponding nodes in the DPROJ (where adding dependencies in the DPK should, upon compile, inject the corresponding nodes into the DPROJ).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I didn't know that my changes in the `requires` section disappear when adding a new dependency! I just tested adding and removing the conditional symbol. It doesn't affect the .dproj. The reference just stays there.

Comment: If you remove the reference in the DPROJ, then recompile with the unit reference, does it prompt to add that dependency again? If so, the only thing I can think of is to remove the DPROJ reference manually every time you intend to distribute your project.

It may be easier to do two alternative packages: One with the dependency, one without... but again, this isn't really elegant!

Comment: Delphi doesn't seem to care about anything I do to the references in the .dproj. If I delete them, it recreates them sometimes, sometimes not. Sometimes switching to a different build config in the IDE triggers it, sometimes not. Strange.

Comment: It's perhaps one of those occasions where you need to do a Clean/Build as opposed to just Shift+F9 or "Compile".

Comment: This isn't particularly one of Delphi's "strong points", as it seems to treat packages quite "rigidly", with little-to-no flexibility for things like conditional dependencies!